# how to display toast message before onPause() in android?

Tags: java, android, toast

I am attempting to display a toast message before the activity pauses by overriding onPause method with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    super.onPause();
}
```

according to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle
activity will not be paused until this method is returned:

```
"Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns."
```

However toast message is not displayed at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:
`Toast.makeText(this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`

to:

`Toast.makeText(this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

Comment: Thank you ++. It is late in the night I did not notice it.